# Assign an event handler of a Form Control to another class

Tags: events, controls, handler

There are some questions about this issue, and the conclusion is that you can't assign an event handler to a Form Control "outside" the Form code. So I found a method of doing that without nay restriction.
First action is to make a public Sub in the Form (let's say Form1), that will assign a Click event to any control
The Idea is to pass the Control Parent Object, the Control Name as a String and the Address of Sub as EventHandler. If you pass directly the control as it it is received in the other class, it is not working
The control must be "directly" on the form. If there are controls in container controls, then the reference must be set to the form's Controls, not the container:

```
Public Sub AddClick(par as Object, cname AS String, evH as EventHandler)
    Dim con As Control
    If par is Me then con = Controls(cname) Else _
        con = Controls(par.Name).Controls(cname)
    AddHandler con.Click, evH
End Sub
```

So a control of a Form1 is passed as parameter in another class (that could be any object), and from that we assign the Event

```
Class x
    
    Public Sub GetControl(con AS control)
        Form1.AddClick(con.Parent, con.Name, AddressOf ClickHandler)
    End Sub
    
    Public Sub ClickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        'Do something
    End Sub

End Class
```

With that method you can "assign" Form1 buttons, checkboxes etc to various class objects (or modules) in order to have all code in other class and not in the form.